# Is there a way to connect two bones to one?

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm rigging a cat with two tails, using the default rigify cat armature is there a way to connect an extra tail rig to the main spine in any way? is there an easier method to achieve control of two different tails connected to one spine?

Answer (score 0):

You can 'Parent' the extra tail to the same 'Bone' that the original tail is parented to. A Bone can have multiple 'children' but only one parent.

Comment: This ends up having the extra tail's bone face the opposite way..i should add rigify has is where the tail is actually the parent I believe? every other bone is under it

Comment: Not true, Rigify is just a collection of sub-rigs, those bones that are backwards are just the 'Control' bones. There are many layers of bones, look in the 'Armature' panel under 'Skeleton'. Since your using Rigify, you should duplicate the tail section BEFORE you hit the 'Generate' button.